# Find Hash algorithm while hash value and original value are available

Tags: hash, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

In this case i have clear Text password also i have hashed value of this password,so i need to know how can i find out what hashing algorithm was used and is it possible to use it for hashing another clear text password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sums of a algoithm hast spezific length. This is Your First step.

Then you muss encod The Clear Text until you find The hashsum

Sorry send from German iphone

Comment: Thank you Denis but i didnt  get your idea, could you explain a little more??

Comment: Yes! show to the wiki page of sha1 http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm  you see all examples have the same length of the key. So you know which HASH Familie it is. After this you can test password + salt -> HASH Algo1 , Algo2, etc.

Comment: Hey Denis my hash is 48 bit Lenght,do you have any idea about this!!

Comment: Actually this is my hash, 200004531170100000044e8060e9c62606470f81feceba4 and the original value is one of these VC1KJ000E3CFE, VC1WJ000E3D90

Comment: Maybe SHA-384 because 48byte * 8 = 384bit
Here is a list for the most Hash Alogos:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions